# output of the c format for gdb x command

Tags: c, gdb

From the documentation at [1], an example output for the `gdb x` command in c format is as follows:

```
(gdb) x/c testArray
0xbfffef7b: 48 '0'
(gdb) x/5c testArray
0xbfffef7b: 48 '0' 49 '1' 50 '2' 51 '3' 52 '4'
```

What does these numbers, such as `48, 49, 50` in the output mean?

Is it some kind of relative address?

Thank you very much!

[1] http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/x

Comment: Have a look at `man ascii`, you might find your answer there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is displaying the memory contents at a given address using the given format.

In your specific case, `x/5c` is displaying the first 5 bytes at the memory location `testArray`, and printing the bytes as a `char`.

The first 5 bytes of `testArray` are the characters `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` (the value in single quotes). The value before is the decimal value of the char.